# Nullpointerexception in gps, only on specific devide: nexus 7, galaxy tab 2 and asus tab

Tags: gps, nullpointerexception

The nullpointerexception appears only in specific device: nexus 7, galaxy tab 2 and some Asus tab device.
Inicialize gps sensor :

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locListener);
```

I think that the object Location of method onlocationchanged is different to another device, how much work? Is not really gps sensor?
The point of exception is :
code//

```
private void mostrarPosicion(Location loc) { 
    try {       if(loc != null)
                { double alturaf;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#"); 
              try{      longi=loc.getLongitude(); } catch(NullPointerException e){      textView1.setText("error longitude"); longi=0;}
             try {lat=loc.getLatitude();} catch(NullPointerException e){textView1.setText("erro latitude");lat=0;}
             if(longi==0){longi=0.0000001;}
             if(lat==0){lat=0.00000001;}
             if (lat>35 && longi<55 && longi>(-24)){ europa();}
```

.... //$

the try produces exception is the line if(loc!=null)

In my manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" 
              android:required="true" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?